# How do I get a "my computer" icon on the desktop in Kali linux?

Tags: linux, kali-linux, desktop-customization

How do I get a "my computer" icon on the desktop in Kali Linux rolling edition 2016.1 and get access to the hard drives?

I tried `dconf-editor` through the terminal, then I navigated to org/gnome`/nautilus/desktop`. I can't find any option to show/hide the "my computer" icon.

Could anyone tell me how can my queries be solved?

[image: Screen shot here]!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note;**

---

There is no 'My computer as such'. But you can make one :P. *hard to do*

Make sure your kali linux is up to date.

e.g. apt-get update && apt-get upgrade && apt-get dist-upgrade

**Making a custom My computer folder**

---

*Of course the simplest solution is to just go to 'other locations' on your nautilus side bar....*

**Some stuff I do;**

[image: What Dconf Should look like]

dconf -> org/gnome/nautilus/prefrences/show-create-link

***You can come back and disable this after***

cd ~/***your location of folder***

e.g. ~/Documents/

mkdir "My Computer"

Right click, make link. ***<- You enabled this with dconf***

Put link on desktop..

You now have a folder link. Put whatever you want in the folder. Such as say, mounted harddrives!

***Mounting harddrives***

---

You should write a script with bash to automate this process! *then run it on startup*

Next you will need to follow this guide, and mount your harddrives to that folder.

The command-line solution:

```
to check which drives your system can see:

sudo fdisk -l
```

If your drive is in the list, you'll be able to see what partitions are on the drive, like this:

Disk /dev/sda: 160.0 GB, 160041885696 bytes
...

```
   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *          63      208844      104391   83  Linux
/dev/sda2          208845     2313359     1052257+  82  Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda3         2313360   312576704   155131672+  83  Linux
```

Then create a directory somewhere and mount one of the partitions.

For example, to mount a FAT32 partition located at dev/sda3 read-only into directory /media/my_test_mount you can do

```
sudo mount -t cifs -o ro /dev/sda3 /media/my_test_mount
```

This approach gives you more control, as you can use different mount options, for example mount the partition read-only.

See man mount for details.

Credit 
[Sergey](https://askubuntu.com/questions/182446/how-do-i-view-all-available-hdds-partitions)

***P.s. need to work on my answer formatting, but I gave it my best shot :P***

Comment: Stuck at the first step. There's no show-create-link. Now what shall I do?

Comment: Could you provide me some more information, such as gnome version etc.

If your using anything below 3.20.1 I recommend you type apt-get update && apt-get upgrade && apt-get dist-upgrade

Comment: My gnome version is 3.18.1. I ran the code: apt-get update && apt-get upgrade && apt-get dist-upgrade  then apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool.
The output is: gnome-tweak-tool is already the newest version (3.18.1 -1).
Now, is there any way to update it?

Comment: Currently Kali-Linux uses 3.20.1, try rebooting computer. If this does not work then use the gnome update tool. *package updater in search menu*

Comment: I found v3.20.2 [here](https://mail.gnome.org/archives/devel-announce-list/2016-May/msg00001.html) . But I didn't find any help form internet to install such file. Can you tell me how such file can be installed?

Comment: @007mrviper Have you tried fully updating, and using the package updater? And rebooting?

Comment: Could u plz take a look at this [question](http://superuser.com/questions/1077271/how-to-install-or-upgrade-to-gnome-v3-20-x-in-kali-linux)?

Answer (score -1):

may this will help

**in Ubuntu**

> all the file in /usr/share/applications/ with extension *desktop*. Copy them to desktop and make them executable, then they are clickable icons
>   or `find / -name "*.desktop" 2> /dev/null | grep computer` finds all candidates, cp to desktop

1. you can open any of them with gedit/vim/nano/micro
2. modify it (usually the *Exec=* line) eg. `nautilus -g "120x40" /home/$USER`
3. `save as` it to desktop with desktop extension and `chmod u+x` it
4. now it's clickable

Comment: Clearly states kali linux, and this does not even begin to solve the problem.