# How to install or upgrade to gnome v3.20.X in Kali Linux?

Tags: linux, upgrade, gnome, kali-linux, desktop-customization

I am running gnome v3.18.1 on Kali Linux & want to upgrade to gnome v3.20.X.
Steps I followed:
`apt-get update && apt-get upgrade && apt-get dist-upgrade`
`apt-get install gnome-shell`
**Output:**
[Image](https://photos.google.com/u/3/photo/AF1QipP5g96mjS2J7aVrd5MhC3f8f9noACHspO24rfde)

I also tried to update through ***Package Updator*** & ***Packages*** but no updates were available.
But, I found update package [here](https://mail.gnome.org/archives/devel-announce-list/2016-May/msg00001.html) but don't know how to install such files.
Guys, need help to install such file. Thanks!

Comment: Could you please type cat /etc/apt/source.list into console, and put the output, would be much appreciated

Comment: Installing from source packages, specifically on kali, is not in your best interests, and is quite difficult. Troubleshooting why your pc is not updating will probably be more worthwhile any way.

Comment: @Tealkine How can I check the version of linux repository that I'm currently using?

Comment: @Tealkine After uncommenting the lines in repository, I ran the code  `apt-get clean && apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y && apt-get dist-upgrade -y`. After the update, I ran the code `apt-get install gnome-tweak tool` then `apt-get install gnome-shell`
Output: [Image](https://photos.google.com/u/3/photo/AF1QipOvLZhTgVRBcgLq-YcCaCvddPFtA1YNaQ0bAwX4)
Why wasn't my gnome-shell updated?Where did I go wrong?